# iterating a list inside another list in R

Tags: r

I have a question about iterating over a list inside another list.

Suppose we have two lists: `true_indices_list_1` and `true_indices_list_2`

`true_indices_list_1` contains the following.

```
$`1`
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4

$`2`
[1] 11

$`3`
[1] 33,34

$`4`
[1] 22

$`5`
[1] 11

$`6`
[1] 100
```

true_indices_list_2 contains the following.

```
$`1`
[1] 5, 6, 7, 8

$`2`
[1] 9

$`3`
[1] 10,11

$`4`
[1] 12
```

Both of these lists are in another list named 'true_indices_list'.

Now, the purpose of this code is to add adjacent integer to every element of the list. For example:

`true_indices_list_1` should be as follows:

```
$`1`
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

$`2`
[1] 11, 12

$`3`
[1] 33, 34, 35

$`4`
[1] 22, 23

$`5`
[1] 11, 12

$`6`
[1] 100, 101
```

AND
`true_indices_list_2` should be as follows:

```
$`1`
[1] 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

$`2`
[1] 9, 10

$`3`
[1] 10,11, 12

$`4`
[1] 12, 13
```

To achieve this, I wrote the following code.

```
for (i in true_indices_list) {
  
  for (j in seq(1,length(i),1)){
  

i$`j`[length(i$`j`)+1] <-  i$`j`[length(i$`j`)] + 1

  }
  
}
```

This did not work.. so I also tried this:

```
for (i in true_indices_list) {
  
  for (j in seq(1,length(i),1)){
  

i[[j]][length([[j]])+1] <-  [[j]][length([[j]])] + 1

  }
  
}
```

Unfortunately, Something is wrong and it is not working.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this code..

Thanks...

Comment: Based on the example showed, your lists have different length and you may need to check for each element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is best done without a loop at all. Instead, you can use a nested `lapply`. Suppose your data looks like this:

```r
true_indices_list <- list(
  true_indices_list_1 = list("1" = 1:3,
                             "2" = 5:10,
                             "3" = 34:40),
  true_indices_list_2 = list("1" = 23:27,
                             "2" = 2:8)
  )

true_indices_list$true_indices_list_1
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

true_indices_list$true_indices_list_2
#> $`1`
#> [1] 23 24 25 26 27
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Then you can do:

```r
true_indices_list <- lapply(true_indices_list, lapply, function(x) append(x, max(x) + 1))
```

And now you have

```r
true_indices_list$true_indices_list_1
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41

true_indices_list$true_indices_list_2
#> $`1`
#> [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `rapply` could help

```
> rapply(true_indices_list,function(v) c(v,tail(v,1)+1),how = "replace")
$true_indices_list_1
$true_indices_list_1$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$true_indices_list_1$`2`
[1] 11 12

$true_indices_list_1$`3`
[1] 33 34 35

$true_indices_list_1$`4`
[1] 22 23

$true_indices_list_1$`5`
[1] 11 12

$true_indices_list_1$`6`
[1] 100 101


$true_indices_list_2
$true_indices_list_2$`1`
[1] 5 6 7 8 9

$true_indices_list_2$`2`
[1]  9 10

$true_indices_list_2$`3`
[1] 10 11 12

$true_indices_list_2$`4`
[1] 12 13
```

**Data**

```
> dput(true_indices_list)
list(true_indices_list_1 = list(`1` = 1:4, `2` = 11, `3` = 33:34, 
    `4` = 22, `5` = 11, `6` = 100), true_indices_list_2 = list(
    `1` = 5:8, `2` = 9, `3` = 10:11, `4` = 12))
```